# Separate content the single column into multiple column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tabula-py

I am working project to convert pdf file into table using tabule python. Where while scanning the tabula detect such table, but one such column as table is as below in [image: picture_1] while the actually image of table is as below picture_2[image: picture_1]

Is there any method using python to single column into separate column, like second picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with expand=True.

example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([["Purchase Balance"],["138 303"]])
>>> df
                0
0  Purchase Balance
1           138 303

>>> df[0].str.split(" ", expand=True)
         0        1
0  Purchase  Balance
1       138      303
```

Comment: But what about two string(Purchase and Value) in two row, how to combine them in one row As Purchase Value and also for other attribute also eg. Balanced Units/Nos, Average Price and many more?

Comment: you can add two rows in pandas. something like `df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0] + df.iloc[1]` and then drop the unwanted row like `df.drop(1, axis=0)`.